# WPF Invisible Cross cursor over gray background

Tags: c#, wpf

The WPF `Cursors.Cross` becomes invisible on a gray (#ff808080) background.

I noticed the cross cursor automatically inverts the background color for better visual perception. But in case of gray color, the inversion algorithm doesn't work so well. See picture below:

[image: WPF invisible Cross cursor]

Windows10, .net 4.5

Note: Might be related to [Caret disappears when the background of a textbox is gray in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22710355/197377) but the proposed solution does not apply for the mouse cursor.