# How to style a WPF Textbox caret.

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to style the caret within a TextBox in wpf?  Changing the color is easy enough, but I need to change the shape.  How do I go about finding this template?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution, though it does use code behind.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633935/Customizing-the-Caret-of-a-WPF-TextBox

It appears that only the color can be changed with a style.

[TextBox Caret Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290667/textbox-caret-styling)

Comment: I read this article prior to posting and was hoping there was a better way to achieve this.