# Set normal cursor on textbox

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is possible remove this cursor:

[image]

and put the default arrow in the TextBlock? I actually tried the property

```
IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True"
```

but nothing has changed, also I want understand if is possible remove the focus on the TextBox where the mouse is hover, actually I tried: `Focusable="False"`
but also not working.

Comment: I wanted to mark this as duplicate but since the OP didn't mark it, it won't allow me. However [this is correct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816597/how-to-style-a-wpf-textbox-caret).

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `Cursor` property to `Arrow` and the `CaretBrush` property to `Transparent`:

```
<TextBox Cursor="Arrow" CaretBrush="Transparent" />
```

> also I want understand if is possible remove the focus on the TextBox where the mouse is hover, actually I tried: Focusable="False" but also not working.

Please only ask one question in one post and then create a new one if you have another issue.

But to remove the focus highlight you should modify the control template of the `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Cursor="Arrow" CaretBrush="Transparent">
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```